# What is the attribute in Xunit that's similar to TestContext in Visual studio tests?

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

We are migrating from visual studio tests to xunit.. In VStests we can access run time test parameters using TestContext. I am looking to set a global variable in the tests supplied at run time from command line using msbuild. Can someone help in finding out the TestContext equivalent in xunit?

Comment: 99% sure it's not a faciility xUnit has or wants - pass via env vars (or add an embedded resource to the assembly and read in body of test if static)

Comment: See: https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html

Comment: @RubenBartelink: thank you for your inputs figured out by using env vars...

Comment: Hi Swathi , Can you please let me know how did you do using Env Variables. As i am new to C# it would be good if you could provide me with an example.

Answer (score 4):

[There is no `TestContext` in XUnit](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/594).

I could not find a canonical way to deal with environment parameters when running the tests, so I relied on a JSON file. E.g.:

```
{
  "Browser": "Chrome",
  "BasePath": "localhost:4200",
  "BaseApiPath": "http://localhost:50204/"
}
```

### C# code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "environment.json");
string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
Configuration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestingConfiguration>(json);
```